# How do I enable the Redemption Plugin in Outlook 2016 / 365

Tags: outlook-redemption

We were using Outlook 2007 and upgraded to 365...now our application fails with redemption.  I have installed the newest version...but it doesnt look enabled in Outlook???

I have tried going in and enabling it but only says use a url or xml file?

Please help

Comment: I can give you the error message but it is too hard

Comment: try to simplify it and post it

Answer (score 0):

Redemption hasn't been installing itself as an Outlook addin for  quite a few years now. 
How exactly does the error manifest itself?

Comment: System.Exception: Cannot create ActiveX component.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject(String ProgId, String ServerName)
   at StandardLibrary2.MicrosoftOutlook.SendEmail(String Address, String cc, String bcc, String Subject, String Body, String[] attachments)
   at StandardLibrary2.RoutinesGeneral.SendEmailUsingRedemption(String EmailAddress, String EmailCc, String EmailBcc, String Subject, String Body,

Comment: at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: Did you register the dll(s) with regsvr32.exe? Does the bitness of your app match the bitness of Outlook? http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject

Comment: I did.  So our database was built and we used to use Office 2007 and then just moved to Office 365.  I know it all worked with Office 2013 as well but not 365.  The database tries to interact with Outlook creating the emails and embedding email addresses, subject line, attachments etc...sometimes placing the email into the outbox etc.  The error we get looks like what would happen in the past when Redemption wasnt installed.  We would reinstall and it would work.  Now we just get the error.  I am not a programmer..but i can have them comment as well.  Does that help?